# Output values from all entries in a specific section EXCEPT those with a specific category id

Tags: categories, entry, category, output, id

Currently, this is NEARLY doing what I want except instead of the output being entries that do NOT have the id, it's output is ONLY the entries with the id.  I'm not sure why, since I've included the 'not' keyword within the parameter.

```
{% set entries = 
craft.entries.section('driverPositions').limit(null).relatedTo('not' , 7192) %}

{% for entry in entries.order('state, city').limit(null) %}

<option value="{{entry.url}}">{{ entry.state }} - {{ entry.city }}</option>

{% endfor %}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the entry IDs that have are related to the category and then exclude them from the all the entries.

```
{% set entryIdsWithCategory = 
craft.entries.section('driverPositions').relatedTo('7192').limit(null).ids() %}

{% set entryIdsWithoutCategory = craft.entries.section('driverPositions').limit(null).ids()|without(entryIdsWithCategory) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('businesses').limit(null).id(entryIdsWithoutCategory).order('state, city') %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <option value="{{entry.url}}">{{ entry.state }} - {{ entry.city }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```